# British Summer Time - BST not recognised by SimpleDateFormat timezone

Tags: android

`SimpleDateFormat` parse works in a JUnit test (Robolectric test runner), but fails if run on device.

```
@Test
public void testDateParse() throws ParseException {
    String datetime = "Wed Sep 03 12:59:27 BST 2014";

    new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
            .parse(datetime);
}
```

When it fails on the device the exception says:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Sep 03 12:59:27 BST 2014" (at offset 20)
```

Offset 20 is the `B` of `BST`, so it's timezone related.

Indeed `"GMT"` works: `String datetime = "Wed Sep 03 12:59:27 GMT 2014";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the interesting question here is why does this run ok on Robolectric but fails to run on an Android test.

Robo runs on the JVM and there is a difference in behaviour for Timezone parsing between Android and good ol' Java.

In the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone(java.lang.String)):

> Other than the special cases "UTC" and "GMT" (which are synonymous in this context, both corresponding to UTC), Android does not support the deprecated three-letter time zone IDs used in Java 1.1.

In the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone(java.lang.String)):

> the ID for a TimeZone, either an abbreviation such as "PST", a full name such as "America/Los_Angeles", or a custom ID such as "GMT-8:00". Note that the support of abbreviations is for JDK 1.1.x compatibility only and full names should be used.

So the answer is that the 3-letter abbreviations should not be used (because they are ambiguous), but *can* be used on the JVM for compatibility reasons, but not on Android.

Comment: Hello, @Alex Florescu  so how we can solve this issue if we are getting "BST"  in date