# What to test with Robolectric?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, robolectric

It seems to me that I am fundamentally misunderstanding the purpose of Robolectric. I've been battling with it for a week already, and so far getting a new error message is considered as making progress. I am able to test some basic stuff like static views in an activity, but when something more complicated things come into play things just fall apart. I had to extend Robolectric to support 3-rd party libraries with certain parameters, Appcompat action bars and numerous other things which was extremely time-consuming and wasn't really documented anywhere, and things are advancing at a pretty much glacial pace. I am starting to think that I am using it in a wrong way and it simply isn't supposed to do what I want it to do.

The general app logic is quite straightforward so there isn't really much to unit test, the most complicated stuff is in the UI and remote API calls. Is Robolectric just supposed to make unit testing for Android less painful than with JUnit because it can run on the JVM and supports a few Android classes? Perhaps a black-box behaviour testing framework like Espresso would be more suitable for my needs? But we use continuos integration, and Robolectric was nice and easy to set up to run tests on the CI server, and I'd kind of like to keep it that way.

What do you use Robolectric for? A lot of blog posts recommend it for "activity lifecycle testing", but since I'm also quite new in the Android world, I don't really understand the purpose of it, especially since the app I'm testing is portrait-only. Could someone please give an overview of what you use Robolectric for, and how do you do it, preferably with code examples and explain why and how those tests are important?

Comment: I think you would be better of in [the programmers exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour). It is about conceptual questions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but there is a [somewhat similar question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/178244/in-which-cases-robolectric-is-a-relevant-solution/254149) there, it doesn't have very relevant answers and it's closed. Here I'm asking more for specific use cases that people actually use with code examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use it for:

- unit testing: all components from parsers and utils, to controllers and presenters
- integration/acceptance testing:  the business logic of the app, per screen (which falls into integration and/or acceptance testing)

We don't use it for (and have found it difficult to use for these):

- testing the network layer (we run all tests by injecting the test data in the same way the network layer would; parsers are tested separately)
- user flows through different screens

If you're looking for more of the latter, perhaps Espresso/Robotium are better suited for your needs. And you absolutely *can* run these as part of your CI pipeline, but you'll need to invest some time in setup, or integrating with something like Appurify.

If you are finding it very difficult to write your tests, it might have to do more with the way your app is architected than the way you're using robolectric. See my answer here as well, it might help you: [Writing Android acceptance tests with robolectric: how could it be done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154337/writing-android-acceptance-tests-with-robolectric-how-could-it-be-done/26161257#26161257)

Comment: A nice answer, thanks! Can you please elaborate a bit more on the "user flows" part - I use Robolectric to test if the correct activity/fragment is starting on a button press or event, does it fall into "business logic of the app, per screen" category, or "user flows" category? And could you please give and example of your controller and presenter unit tests?

Comment: It's easy to test that for some action on a screen, another screen will be opened. I would recommend against testing two screens at once (e.g. test screen A, test transition to screen B, then test screen B), which could very well be a valid user flow. That's better done in UI tests.

Comment: Oh yeah, I don't test two screens at once. The test still don't seem to be "true" unit tests because they sometimes involve a few methods from the class, but I definitely to limit them to maximum one activity/fragment.